# Debian firewall drop all but except Postfix doesn't work

Tags: linux, networking, email, debian, firewall

I set up my Linux firewall but it doesn't work to let my email-client connect to the server when the rule "drop everything" is activated. I also changed the order of the rules with no effect. Here is the configuration:

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Do you have any idea what's the reason for that?

Comment: Do you have an OUTPUT or FORWARD chain at all? All I see here is an INPUT chain, which wouldn't be able to see a response (since the server can't send)

Comment: Yes. I have declared them:

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)      
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)    
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere